# Generating new rows using information from rows and columns with awk

Tags: awk

I have a file where the input is in the format described below in the input code. "word" "frq" and "word_meanings" would correspond to columns 1, 2, and 3. In column 1 there are words, in column 2 there are numbers, and in column 3 there are meanings for the words. I want to pair the meanings in column 3 with each other so that in the output they are in the same row if they have the same "word" for column 1. I also want to use the number in the "frq" column to decide how these meanings are paired with one another.

Input:

```
word frq  word_meanings

door  12  meaning_a
door  25  meaning_b
door  3   meaning_c
hand  20  meaning_d
hand  17  meaning_e
floor 4   meaning_f
floor 30  meaning_g
floor 20  meaning_h
floor 4   meaning_e
```

The output would be something like

```
door meaning_b meaning_a
door meaning_b meaning_c
hand meaning_d meaning_e
floor meaning_g meaning_h
floor meaning_g meaning_e
floor meaning_g meaning_f
```

For the explanation, because 'meaning_b' has a frq value of 25, it has the highest frq value for all the columns which start with the word door, therefore 'meaning_b' is then used to create pairs with the other meanings in the other rows which have door as the word for the first column.

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: @John1024 I'm completely stuck, I don't know enough to know how to combine different things and even if I did this combination would not give me the pairs I'm looking for (even if it worked) but this is where I'm at   `awk '{x[++$1]} NR==1{j=$2;line=$0} $2>j{line=$0}END{for (i in x) print $0}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making two passes over the file you can use the first to collect the meanings with the highest frequencies and the second to print out each row with those meanings.

The standard way to do that in awk is with `NR` and `FNR`.  When `NR == FNR` (current overall record number equals record number within the current file), you know you are processing the file for the first time. By ending that block with a `next` statement, you skip the action that follows and go directly to reading the next line of the file.

If you reach the second action block you know you are reading the file for the second time where you can print the results for each line.

Don't forget to pass the file twice on the awk command line! Once for each pass.

This technique works great for all kinds of "join" applications (in this case, a self-join).

```
$ cat words.txt
door  12  meaning_a
door  25  meaning_b
door  3   meaning_c
hand  20  meaning_d
hand  17  meaning_e
floor 4   meaning_f
floor 30  meaning_g
floor 20  meaning_h
floor 4   meaning_e


$ cat words.awk
NR == FNR {
    # first pass, build array of meanings with max freq
    if (max_frq[$1] < $2) {
      max_frq[$1] = $2;
      max_meaning[$1] = $3;
    }
    next;
}

{
    # second pass, print words and meanings with those collected in first pass
    if (max_meaning[$1] != $3) {
       print $1, max_meaning[$1], $3;
    }
}


$ awk -f words.awk words.txt words.txt
door meaning_b meaning_a
door meaning_b meaning_c
hand meaning_d meaning_e
floor meaning_g meaning_f
floor meaning_g meaning_h
floor meaning_g meaning_e
```

**EDIT**

To change the output separator you can set `OFS` on the command line:

```
$ awk -v OFS=, -f words.awk words.txt words.txt
door,meaning_b,meaning_a
door,meaning_b,meaning_c
hand,meaning_d,meaning_e
floor,meaning_g,meaning_f
floor,meaning_g,meaning_h
floor,meaning_g,meaning_e
```

Comment: what would need to be changed so that in the output, the field separator is a comma?

Answer (score 1):

Sort it by word and frq, then let `awk` handle the details:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2nr | 
awk '$1 != word {word = $1; means = $3} means != $3 {print word, means, $3}'
```

Output:

```
door   meaning_b  meaning_a
door   meaning_b  meaning_c
floor  meaning_g  meaning_h
floor  meaning_g  meaning_e
floor  meaning_g  meaning_f
hand   meaning_d  meaning_e
```